# How to redirect and how to output custom messages when loggin is ok or fails

Tags: java, spring, jsp, redirect, spring-security

I'm implementing a login system for a website that I'm building, but I'm very new at spring security. For this reason I have a few questions that I hope someone can help me (for better reference I will enumerate the questions).

1) For example, I have a page howthiswork that is only available if the user is authenticated and have the ROLE_USER and if some one hit this page without been first authenticated the system will redirect to the login page.(that is fantastic and what is to expect). But (always a but) when the user is in the login page and press the banner (the home pag link) and from there try to authenticate, the user will be redirect to the howthiswork. How can I prevent this situation to happen? I still want the redirect to work when the user hit a non authorized page (go to login and then redirect to the hit page) but also if the user leaves the login without any action this redirection will be clean!

2) I had override the loadUserByUsername to check the user information, and I want to throw different exceptions for example, when the user does not exist or when is not confirmed or banned etc. I have there already throw new UsernameNotFoundException("login.error.username.no t.found") and I have a messages.properties files in my resource filepath but in my jsp the SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message has always the bad credential message (I had try to override this in my messages.properties but without success). Can anyone know how I can use my own error messages?

3) In the controller (some controller) we can have the Principal. Is this secure (we can rely that know one will change, let say if I'm ajpcmachado I cant call that controller saying I'm admin)?

My code is:
Login JSP:

```
<c:if test="${not empty SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION}">
        <div id="login-message" style="display:none;" title="<fmt:message key="app.error"/>">
            <span class="ui-icon   ui-icon-circle-close" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 50px 0;"></span>
            <p class="error"><c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}"/></p>
            <c:remove scope="session" var="SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"/>    
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">        
            $( "#login-message" ).dialog({
                    resizable: true,
                    height: "auto",
                    width: 300,
                    modal: true,    
                    dialogClass: 'ui-state-error',
                    buttons : [{
                                "id" : "closeButton",
                                text : '<fmt:message key="app.close"/>',
                                click : function() {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            } ]
                });
        </script>
    </c:if>
<form id="loginuser" name="loginuser" action="<spring:url value="/j_spring_security_check" htmlEscape="true" />" method="POST"  class="login">  
    <div id="user_login">
        <fieldset>
            <dl>
                <input type='text' name='other_email' id='other_email'>    
                <dt><label for="j_username"><fmt:message key="app.username" />:</label></dt>
                <dd><input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" tabindex="1" /></dd>
                <dt><label for="j_password"><fmt:message key="app.password" />:</label></dt>
                <dd><input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" tabindex="2" /></dd>            
                <div style="float:right">
                    <label for="_spring_security_remember_me"><fmt:message key="app.rememberme" /></label>
                    <input type='checkbox' id="_spring_security_remember_me" name='_spring_security_remember_me' style="width:30px !important; vertical-align: middle;" tabindex="3"/>
                </div>
            </dl>
        </fieldset>
        <p class="btn-paragraph">    
            <input type="submit" class="submitLoginButton btn-submit-style" value="<fmt:message key="app.login"/>" />

            <a href="www.google.pt" class="help-link"><fmt:message key="login.recovery" /></a>
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

My Spring-security file

```
<http pattern="/resources/css" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/resources/images" security="none" />
    <http pattern="/resources/js" security="none" />

  <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled">
    </global-method-security>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/accessDenied/">
        <logout logout-success-url="/" invalidate-session="true"/>            
        <intercept-url pattern="/howthiswork/" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>        
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll"/>
        <!-- Set the login page and what to do if login fails -->
        <form-login login-page="/login/" authentication-failure-url="/login/?error=true"/>        

         <remember-me data-source-ref="dataSource"/>

    </http>

    <!-- Use a Sha256 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Sha256 in the database -->
    <beans:bean id ="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" >
         <beans:constructor-arg value="256"/>
         <beans:property name="iterations" value="1024"/>
     </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="loginService" class="com.projectx.standard.services.user.implementation.LoginUserServiceImpl"/>

<authentication-manager>    
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="loginService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <salt-source user-property="username"/>
        </password-encoder>      
    </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```

The LoginService.java:

```
@Override
    @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserDetails user = null;
        RegisteredUserDTO a = this.registeredUserServiceDAO.getRegisteredUserByUsername(username);
        if (a == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("login.error.username.not.found");
        }

        int confirmedStatus = Integer.parseInt(Configuration.getInstance().getValue(SystemConfigEnum.STATUS_CONFIRM));

        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(3);
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        user = new User(a.getUsername(), a.getPwd().toLowerCase(), a.getFkStatus() == confirmedStatus, true, true, true, authList);

        return user;
    }
```

The messages.properties

```
login.recovery=Forgot your password?
login.error=You have entered an invalid email or password!
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.disabled=Your account is disabled. Please press <a href="<c:url value="/useractivation/"/>"> here</a> to send the confirmation email.
login.error.username.not.found = Username not found in the system!
AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials=Invalid username or password  
BindAuthenticator.badCredentials=Invalid username or password
```

Sorry about this long post, but I think is better in one post instead of multiple ones!!

Thank you!

Comment: you should ask one question one time.

Comment: I can divide this question... but I will repeat almost the same source code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this post is a little bit large, but the answers are not to long... so:

1 - Every time someone tries to access to a restricted area, the user is redirected to the login page and this page link is stored into the session SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST (someone correct me if I'm wrong!!). So all you need to do is to clean this attribute when you change page. You can do this in JSLT with

```
<c:remove scope="session" var="SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST"/>
```

2 - Not the best option, but you could raise other exception like DisabledException("...") or any other exception that fits.

3 - I don't think you can change the principal, but I'm the best person to help here... Is just my guess!!